# Python 3.6 Type Annotation in PyCharm Concerning `generator.send(None)`

Tags: python-3.x, generics, pycharm, generator, type-hinting

I am trying to properly type annotate the code in my current project. This includes generators that receive values via `.send()`. Prior to iteration, these generators are sent a `None` for being able to progress to the first `yield.`

In my understanding, the correct type annotation for a generator that yields `TYPE_A`, receives `TYPE_B`, and returns `None` would be

```
Generator[TYPE_A, TYPE_B, None]
```

As the first value sent to the generator can be `None`, however, I figured the following would be more appropriate.

```
Generator[TYPE_A, Optional[TYPE_B], NONE]
```

In PyCharm, this works fine in the most simple case.

```
def f(g: Generator[str, Optional[int], None]):
    g.send(None)
```

The `None` sent to the generator is marked by PyCharm as a type contradiction *only if I replace `Optional[int]` with `int`.*

So far, so good. If I extend this idea with generics, however, either PyCharm gets confused or I am. Consider the following case.

(According to

```
Table = Dict[int, T]     # Table is generic
Messages = Table[bytes]  # Same as Dict[int, bytes]
```

from [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#defining-and-using-generic-types) in PEP483 I feel that the following code should be properly annotated. This time with all imports for easy copy and paste.)

```
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple, Generator, Optional

TYPE_A = TypeVar("TYPE_A")
TYPE_B = TypeVar("TYPE_B")
TUPLE_A = Tuple[TYPE_A, float]
GENERATOR_A = Generator[TUPLE_A, Optional[TYPE_B], None]
GENERATOR_B = Generator[TYPE_B, Optional[TUPLE_A], None]

def example_interactive(system_a: GENERATOR_A[int, str], system_b: GENERATOR_B[str, int]):
    system_b.send(None)
    system_a.send(None)
```

The idea is that `TUPLE_A` features one generic type `TYPE_A` and `GENERATOR_A` and `GENERATOR_B` each have two (one immediate type variable and one mediated over `TUPLE_A`).

[image: type contradiction]

**Unfortunately, PyCharm tells me that it doesn't work like that. Can you please tell me whether I misunderstood something or if type annotations are simply not properly integrated into PyCharm?**

Comment: PyCharm is not good at such type variable substitution. Feel free to file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), maybe [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29564) is related.